# TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

my javascript has code, for one of the pages on my website:

```
$('#nmdt1').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM,
        minDate: nmsdt,
                  ...
                  ...
```

this runs fine, when the page on which id="nmdt1" is loaded.
And I load the related datetimepicker js library (module) only on when i load that page.
so far so good.

but when i load any other pages on my websit i get this error: from the line number where dateformat is defined.

EDIT: here is the correct error for firebug log:

```
TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined
http://myswbsite/jscript/myjsscript.js
Line 569
```

line 569 is:

```
dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM,
```

and yes, this error only comes on page where I am not loading the related js code (jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js). The reason I am not loading this js on every page is, i need it on only one page.

MORE DETAILS:

in HTML header following lib loads (in seq)

```
<head>
    <script src="/jscript/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jscript/myjsscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var mid = "[% mid %]";
        alert('mid='+mid);
        $(".bvmainmenu #"+mid).css({"background":"url(/images/current-bg.gif) top left repeat-x", "color":"#ffffff"});
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

this last javascript code you see above (bottom of header) does not run each time when the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js lib is not loaded (and you see that err in firebug - i can live with error, but why this last code is not running, i am not sure). I am not able to understand why this routine wont run just because i did not load one 'add-on' library

the page which runs everything correctly loads following js scripts in BODY

```
<script src="/jscript/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jscript/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on this page the last javascript code you see in header also loads and displays the alert!

I am having tough time to figure this.

Comment: Are you including the relevant jquery libraries on those pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be saying that this code:

```
$('#nmdt1').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM,
    minDate: nmsdt,
    ...
```

...is within your common `myjsscript.js` script that is loaded on every page. If so, that means it runs on every page and thus you get an error on pages that don't also include the extra plugin scripts.

The code I've quoted above does *not* mean "If an element with that id exists call the `datetimepicker()` method", it means "Create a jQuery object that may or may not have any elements in it and then call the `datetimepicker()` method, passing an object with a property set to `$.datepicker.ATOM`." That is, even if there is no nmdtd1 element on the page it will still call `datetimepicker` and still reference `$.datepicker.ATOM`.

There are at least three ways you can fix this:

1. Move that code out of the common `myjsscript.js` and just put it on the one page that needs it.
2. Go ahead and include the plugin JS files on all the pages on your site - they'll be be cached by the browser, so it's not really a performance hit assuming your users visit several of your pages anyway.
3. Move that code within a conditional so the `.datetimerpicker()` part is not executed unless needed.

For option 3:

```
var $nmdt1 = $('#nmdt1');
if ($nmdt1.length > 0) {
    $nmdt1.datetimepicker({
       dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM,
       minDate: nmsdt,
       ...
    });
}
```

Comment: thx, a lot! i like the 3rd option. Also you correctly understood the situation. I used it, it fixes the error - loads ( i guess it loads all but executes only that portion which satisfies the if condition) the required code.  It also resolved the issue that the last javascript code written within header was not running. so all good now. just one last question: my js file is 28kB - at what size, should i be thinking of segregating the code into js files which are loaded with related pages? any standard? tx again!

Comment: Regarding splitting up your external JS file, it's a matter of opinion. My first preference is to include only common code in a common file.

Comment: thank you. i thought wether i will be able to access functions defined in one common.js file (all functions inside $(document).ready...) from another specific.js file (all functions inside $(document).ready...).  So I looked around and found this page: [http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35451](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=35451) is this correct?

Comment: If your functions are declared _inside_ a document.ready function then they will be scoped as local to that document.ready function and not accessible from _outside_ the document.ready - not even from other code on the same page.

Comment: cant thank you enough. may the force be with you ! :) hurray!!

Answer (score 10):

Have you included [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) in your application.

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Spot on Arun. I had a typo, thus jqueryUI was not referenced correctly.

Comment: That was my case. I updated the jQuery UI package, and the (MVC Net) site was very old, with no bundles defined and the jquery ui file reference was explicitly set with their version numbers in a layout page, so I had to update the file name to the one with the new version number

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that $ is your jquery shortcut identifier. Check the usage of

```
var $J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

In that case try to use `$J.datepicker`