# Disable Specific Dates in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to disable specific dates (multiple amounts) from datepicker in my online booking script. I have looked through handfuls of Google searches for a solution but none of them seem to work with my script.

Edit: When I say it doesn't work with this script, I mean either all of the dates become disabled or the datepicker doesn't appear.

We previously wanted to disable Sundays and BG101 helped us accomplish (thank you) this with

```
$this.datepicker($.extend(dOpts, {
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [(date.getDay() != 0), '']; // 0 => Sunday
    }
}));
```

Any help and guidance would be deeply appreciated.This turned into a 8 hour project :(

Here is my script: http://pastebin.com/xDFxXUeJ

Comment: Go through this [link](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-icons)

Comment: which datepicker you are using jquery datepicker or bootstrap datepicker ??

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We are using jquery datepicker. See code at http://pastebin.com/xDFxXUeJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sorav Garg's** answer is correct for excluding specific days, though you will need to combined the exclude of sunday also:-

Here is an example of excluding all of next week:-

```js
var exclude = ["16-11-2015", "17-11-2015", "18-11-2015", "19-11-2015", "20-11-2015", "21-11-2015"]

$('#calendar').datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [!~$.inArray(day, exclude) && (date.getDay() != 0)];
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="calendar" />
```

Comment: Thank you for stepping in. It's appreciated. I see in your example how it works as I need it too. Although, when implementing it in my code, the datepicker fails to appear when clicking the button after adding suggested edits. Please see code: http://pastebin.com/K48pZJhk - I've been at this all day, 4 AM and still no luck :(

Comment: cannot open pastebin sorry. create a jsfiddle.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hmyx12sz/1/) is the `beforeShowDay` implemented correctly in your code. And [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/er0kb7cw/) is a snippet of your code working.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried implementing the changes, but the datepicker does not appear. I have also tried copying/pasting your edited beforeshowday document in it's entirety, still no luck.

Comment: console errors? without any info I can't help any further.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function book.html:62:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. jquery-1.9.1.js:3346:0
TypeError: jQuery.datepicker is undefined

Comment: you definitely got jqueryui ABOVE your code? inspect the source to be certain.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have attempted using your entire code in it's entirety too.

Comment: sorry mate but I cant help without seeing it myself. it sounds like the scripts are not loading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918991/typeerror-datepicker-is-undefined

Comment: what I would advise to revert back to when it was working with exclude sunday. then add the array line above the `.datepicker(`, then just *replace* the one line inside `beforeShowDay` with 2 lines from above.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this shortly and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You were right. JQuery was not being loaded. I stripped it down and loaded it up again and it is working now according to your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

@mark please try this it will work --

```
for bootstrap datepicker --
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lr3taznx/35/

```
for jquery datepicker --
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/2568/

Comment: This would be our ideal setup. For some reason, when applying it to our code - it does not work. Could it be because we already have "beforeshowday"?

Comment: When implementing it, the calendar no longer appears. Thank you for your effort. Please let me know if you have any other clues. See code at pastebin.com/xDFxXUeJ

Comment: Thank you for your help!